# Spring Boot - load a file in JS code without triggering a controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project with plain JavaScript and jQuery.
For one of the JS plugins, I must load a .ttf font without triggering a controller.
JS code should just read a file from project folder.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on security is configured. If you put the .ttf in src/main/resources/static you will be able to access the file directly without going through a controller. This assumes no security or security configured as

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests()
      .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
```

These static locations include /static/css, /static/js, /static/img, and a few others. If you want to put your .ttf file somewhere other than in the 'common locations' you will have to add your own matcher to allow access to this /static location and permitAll().